# Running a 32-bit application in Debian Wheezy 64 bits: Missing libraries

Tags: 64bit, debian, multiarch

I want to play the game Aquaria in a Debian Wheezy 64 bits. The installation went ok, but when trying to play the game I get these errors:

```
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib control.c:951:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
AL lib: alsa.c:1000: control open (0): No such file or directory
Message: SDL_GL_LoadLibrary Error: Failed loading libGL.so.1
```

I have added 32 bit compatibility with `dpkg --add-architecture i386` and I think that the required libraries are present in the system since typing `locate libasound_module_conf_pulse.so` yields:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so

and `locate libGL.so.1`:

```
/etc/alternatives/glx--libGL.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fglrx/libGL.so.1
```

However, it seems that Debian is ignoring them. What can I do to play Aquaria?

**EDIT 1: ldd aquaria**

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77e1000)
libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /opt/Aquaria/./libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0xf7748000)
libopenal.so.1 => /opt/Aquaria/./libopenal.so.1 (0xf76fa000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/Aquaria/./libstdc++.so.6 (0xf760d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xf75c3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/Aquaria/./libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75b8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf7455000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xf7451000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7437000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xf742e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77e2000)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you're missing the 32-bit libraries (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` contains 64-bit libraries).
Now, let's figure out which packages you need for your libraries:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
libasound2-plugins:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

So you need 32-bit versions of these packages:

```
# apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

In general, before you can install any 32-bit libraries, you must add the `i386` architecture to `dpkg`:

```
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# apt-get update
```

**Update**

<s>Since the above didn't solve the `libGL.so.1` issue and it seems from your `ldd` output that Aquaria can see all its required libraries, I googled the `libGL.so.1` error message and two things came up. Please try the following 2 solutions in order:</s>

1. As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150818/message-sdl-gl-loadlibrary-error-failed-loading-libgl-so-1) try symlinking `libGL.so.1`:

   ```
   ln -sv /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
   ```

   Note that I modified the paths from the answer I linked to so that they're relevant to Debian instead.
2. The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79359/hib-games-aquaria-penumbra-cannot-find-libgl-so-1-even-though-it-exists/88115#88115) suggests that you need to install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` (which you've already done) plus `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` (which is what I'm suggesting you try next).

**Update: What finally worked**

```
apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
```

Comment: Just a note for future readers, `dpkg --add-architecture i386` needs to be ran before installing the 32bit packages, which OP has already done.

Comment: Good point. Adding to answer...

Comment: Hi! I did what you suggested and now the `libasound` error doesn't show up, however the `libGL` one still happens. In the package manager, the `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` appears as installed.

Comment: @KioMarv Please paste the output you get when you run `ldd` on the Aquaria executable.

Comment: @JosephR. Done!

Comment: @KioMarv Updating answer.

Comment: @JosephR. Did you mean `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` instead of `/usr/i386-linux`? And this is strange. Synaptics says that `libGL.so.1` is installed in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`, but if I do `ls -la` in that directory, `libGL` isn't there, only `libGLU`.

Comment: Also, `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` is already installed.

Comment: @KioMarv Yes, I meant `/usr/lib/i386...` Answer corrected. Are you sure you didn't just miss `libGL.so.1` in the directory listing? On my system, it's listed in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `dpkg -S` shows it's from the `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` package.

Comment: @JosephR. I forgot to tell that my video card is an ATI Radeon HD 4500 and I had to install the `fglrx-legacy` driver. And yes, I'm sure that only `libGLU` is in that directory. `dpkg -S libGL.so.1` prints (among other directories): `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2`. But doing a `ls /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2` prints: `ls: cannot access /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2: No such file or directory`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9747/discussion-between-joseph-r-and-kio-marv)

Comment: Hey! I don't know if you get a notification in the chat, but I tried what you suggested and still nothing. I put the `locate libGL.so.1` list in the chat.

Comment: @KioMarv Hi. Have you tried symlinking the existing `libGL` to the required location? Try `ln -s /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

Comment: @JosephR. Hi!! Yes, that did it! I'll accept your answer, so can you edit it and add the link solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KioMarv Since you know better than me what finally worked, how about suggesting an edit to the answer to make it as you would like to see it?

Comment: @KioMarv I took a shot at editing the answer, please correct me if I missed something.

Comment: It's everything fine!