# Segmentation fault in libGL.so.1

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault, multiarch

A while back I posted a question about [running a 32 bit app in Debian Wheezy 64 bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/running-a-32-bit-application-in-debian-wheezy-64-bits-missing-libraries)

Thanks to [@JosephR](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26909/joseph-r) I was able to run it without the nasty `could not find libGL.so.1` error.

Now, however, the app crashes out in the middle of the execution. In the terminal appeared this message after the crashdown:

```
Aug  2 10:04:16 acs-laptop kernel: [  213.472753] aquaria[7006]: segfault at 8 ip 00000000f41238fb sp 00000000ffceabc0 error 4 in libGL.so.1.2[f4107000+54000]
```

Reinstalling the driver did not solved the problem and I'm not sure what it's causing it. Is there a bug in running the 32 bit version of `libGL.so` in a 64 bit system?

Comment: what is the output of `ldd` with `ldd yourProgram` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `libgl1-mesa-glx` you've installed is a free implementation of the OpenGL API.

Usually proprietary drivers ship their own binary implementation (optimized, hardware accelerated).

You've re-installed the driver (how? which?) but probably it install the amd64 libGL version, instead the game look for the i386 (that's way nothing happen)

You may verify which version is used when the game is running with something like:

`grep libGL /proc/$(pidof aquaria)/maps`

or use again the `ldd` command that been suggested in the previous post.

Anyway the problem may be that the game is using some feature not implemented in your libGL, or using a feature in a unexpected way, the only way to know what is wrong is *debugging*.

You may want to install the `libgl1-mesa-glx-dbg:i386` package and maybe instead of numbers you'll get some function name when the segfault happen.

I never used `gdb` from a 64 machine to debug a 32 binary (I'll check) but a `backtrace` would be useful to begin.

Then if [this](http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/06/Aquaria-goes-open-source) is the aquaria you are playing.. it is open source (not the game data) that mean there are good possibility to get it working or even build the game to run 64 native.

**edit**

- [this](http://hg.icculus.org/icculus/aquaria/) is the original repository
- [this](https://github.com/fgenesis/Aquaria_clean) is a *fork*
- [here](http://www.bit-blot.com/forum/index.php?topic=2304.msg31845#msg31845) the forum with some useful information, **read** about the script to cp after installing new binaries
- and [here](https://launchpad.net/~vincent-c/+archive/aquaria/+packages) pre-built packages for ubuntu amd64 and i386, with some lucky you can try to install the deb as it is, or at lease extract the `aquaria` executable from the amd64 `.deb`

if you are going to try something of this ... **backup** your working copy first

Comment: Hi Alex! I'll try your suggestions and post any updates! The Aquaria game I'm playing is from the Humble Bundle.