# Cannot install java after apt-get upgrade

Tags: debian, java

When I execute java -version, I get this:

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I followed multiple online guides towards installing java. I followed all the steps but I still get that error. Maybe I did it wrong - I don't know.

Output of: `dpkg -l jdk*`

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching jdk*
```

Output of: `ls -l /usr/bin/java`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov 16 17:21 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Output of: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

```
add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Output of: `file "$(readlink -e "$(type -P java)")"`

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, BuildID[sha1]=0x6849323f527575e206a1b6449617e809158e82be, not stripped
```

Output of `ldd "$(readlink -e "$(type -P java)")`

```
not a dynamic executable
```

Debian version, Ouput of `uname -a`:

```
Linux Cyneox 3.7-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.7.2-0+kali8 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

@Teresa E Junior

Sorry, I can't comment to these posts for some reason, static linking problem.
The python-software-properties returned this error, which is what I get for most of the programs I try to install:

```
    E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

Also, I ran the command that you stated above, and typing java -version still doesn't do anything.

Joseph R, this was all I typed:

```
root@Cyneox:/usr/bin# apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs

root@Cyneox:/usr/bin# apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jre is not available, but is referred to by another      package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jre' has no installation candidate
```

But the first 2 lines that you gave me worked.

The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20130905-07:57]/ kali contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot amd64     LIVE/INSTALL     Binary 20130905-07:57]/ kali contrib main non-free

## Security updates
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory
```

Joseph, I applied your fix in the update, and everything was going smoothly... until:

```
Setting up openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u25-2.3.10-1~deb7u1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/java': Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ca-certificates-java:
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 which provides java6-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing ca-certificates-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre:amd64:
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u25-2.3.10-1~deb7u1); however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64:
 icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u25-2.3.10-1~deb7u1); however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre-lib:
 openjdk-7-jre-lib depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~b130~pre0); however:
  Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing openjdk-7-jre-lib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64
 openjdk-7-jre-lib
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I tried `apt-get -f install` but that still failed...

Comment: What do you get with `file "$(readlink -e "$(type -P java)")"`?

Comment: ...and `arch`? Please don't forget to ping me in the comments to indicate that you've updated the question.

Comment: Also, what do you get with `ldd "$(readlink -e "$(type -P java)")"`?

Comment: Make sure `openjdk-6-jdk` is installed. Also, please state the version/release of Debian.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Try `mv /etc/alternatives/java{,.bak}` followed by `apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jre`

Comment: note: **immediately remove the archive.canonical.com line from sources.list, then run apt-get update**. mixing Ubuntu packages and Debian packages is dangerous, and you should never do it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds to me like the perennial issue of not being able to run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine. We discussed this issue many times here (see the **References** section at the end of my answer for similar questions).

Assuming you're running Debian Wheezy, you need to add the `i386` architecture first to download 32-bit libraries:

```
# dpkg --add-architecture i386
# apt-get update
# apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs:i386
```

However, don't do that. It seems, as Teresa intuited, that your Java installation is from a third party source, which is why it's 32-bit while you have a 64-bit OS. I recommend you install Java from the repos:

```
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

should do the trick.

**Update**

Based on your additional information, please add the Debian stable repos to your `/etc/sources.list`:

```
# echo 'deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free' >>/etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update # may take a while
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

**Notes**

- The `openjdk-7-jre` is meant to install the Java Runtime Environment, version 7, which is the latest (in the Debian stable repos) at the time of writing. For other versions, replace the `7` appropriately.
- Depending on your convictions regarding software freedom, you may want to remove the `contrib` and `non-free` parts of the above command as they enable you to install proprietary, closed-source software.

**References**

- [Running a 32-bit application in Debian Wheezy 64 bits: Missing libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83773/running-a-32-bit-application-in-debian-wheezy-64-bits-missing-libraries)
- [Getting “Not found” message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do already have Java installed under `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/`, which is not an official path in Debian, but must be the result of installing it from a third party package (eg. the package from Oracle's website). It is just not linked to `/usr/bin`. You can either use Java directly by running it from `/usr/local/` or link it to `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/alternatives/java java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java 1
```

This should be enough. Try running `/usr/bin/java` to see if it works.

Now, regardinng the other method you were trying, there is a confusion in your question: you are using Debian and following instructions on how to install Java in **Ubuntu**. You could also try installing Java from WebUpd8 PPA on Debian, but I can't assure you it would work:

*python-software-properties* contains the command *add-apt-repository*:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Then you could continue following Andrew's instructions, as you've been. The worst that would happen is APT refusing to install Java for you.